# How to calculate the information gain and entropy of a dataset with ten features?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, decision-tree, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset of 10K, and I created the following ten features:

- Distance - (0 or 1)
- IsPronoun - (True or False)
- String Match - (True or False)
- Demonstrative NP - (True if i and j is demonstrative pronoun)
- Number Agreement - (check if i or j is singular or plural pronoun)
- Semantic compatibility - (if i and j semantically compitable)
- Gender agreement - (check if i or j is male/female)
- IsProperNoun - (find i or j is proper noun or not)
- Appositive - (find if i is opposit of j)
- Alias - (find if i is alias of j or vice verses)

Each of the features has an output from the dataset. Now I want to make the tree. But first, how should I calculate the entropy and information gain?

Answer (score 0):

you can use mutual_info_classif from sklearn.feature_selection, but you'll need to define your target (dependent) variable. Assuming all of your attributes are discrete (nominal):

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
print (mutual_info_classif(X_vec, Y, discrete_features=True))
```

Comment: The problem is that the dataset is unstructured and all the feature extract it own output from the dataset. How should I use the sklearn to define the values of x and y or so on?

Comment: So you'll have to structure it first. Y is always the target (dependent) variable - what are you trying to predict? X is the set of independent variables - you use them to predict the target variable.

Comment: Then how should be the structure of the dataset? because we operate on i and j if both have an output for the above-mentioned features.

Comment: Add i and j as features as well

Comment: So it will be a table with 13 column, where the last column will have the output of yes/no?

Comment: yes - but the target variable shouldn't be a part of X - it should be a separate vector

Comment: yes, I take a separate column for target variable where it has the value of 0 or 1, if it is zero it means they are not related other it is related (referred)